# What's Unicode/ASCII's relevance to machine code?

Tags: unicode

Even though machine language varies according to, well, machine, as far as I've found out, Unicode/ASCII has specific values for characters(this whole concept is still a bit confusing). So, basically, is the binary value for the character, let's say, 'A' in Linux different to that of 'A' in Windows? If different machines understand different sequences of 1s and 0s, shouldn't 'A's 1s and 0s differ according to machine(even though Unicode has set values for each character--I think)?
P.S. I'm kind of new to programming and don't even know if this is the right place to ask this question.(If it isn't, sorry!)

Comment: Try [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: You should understand from the comments and answers that " 'A' in Linux" doesn't quite make sense. Bottom-line if someone gives a sequence of bytes and says they represent text, they also have to make sure you know which encoding of which character set they were created with. This could be from specifications, conventions, embedded documentation ([meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) charset in HTML, [encoding](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EncodingDecl) in XML, or [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) header in HTTP.)

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows are different *operating systems*, which can very well run on the same *machine* (hardware). ASCII and Unicode (and the *Unicode encodings* like UTF-8) are standards independent of any specific operating system or machine. These standards define how *data* should be expressed, and that is independent of any specific implementation of that standard. ASCII in Windows is exactly the same as ASCII in Linux, because ASCII has been defined the way it is and different systems must make their implementation conform to that standard if they want to be interoperable.

Now, different hardware architectures may use [big-endian vs. little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architectures, in which case the actual bytes may be processed in a different order internally. But that is merely an *implementation detail*; ASCII will still be ASCII.

Comment: Yes, ASCII will still be ASCII, except when people use ASCII like [Kleenex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark). Watch out for people misusing that name for general concepts. ASCII itself is used only in very specialized contexts.

Comment: Thank you for the replies(: So, the encoding scheme is not related to machine language? And are the sequence of bits of the specified characters in ASCII  the same in all machines(that use ASCII)? As in, for example, since 01000001 is 'A', do all computers that use ASCII understand this sequence as 'A'? I'm not sure I'm making sense with this question; I think I've got the concept of encoding schemes and machine language jumbled up.

Comment: You are almost there. Whether a sequence of bytes is treated as text is up to the program or operating system, not the machine. A program like a web browser loading a web page uses the encoding that the server says to use. The Windows operating system uses UTF-16 for names in its NTFS file system. A compiler or assembler uses either a default encoding that you should know and/or lets you tell it which encoding you saved the source code file with. A console program (aka shell, terminal, command prompt) has an encoding setting. Go `locale` or `chcp` to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Machines don't "understand" characters. They process bytes, made of 0 and 1s.